# "Query set has no attribute <field>" but I'm not doing any field lookup

Tags: python, django

In Django I'm using `filter` to return a Queryset so I can update it in my serializer. The problem is I get getting this error: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'vin'`. I understand the error occurs when you try to lookup a field on a Queryset, in which case you would use `get()` instead of `filter()`, but I'm not doing a field lookup. And my database *does* get updated as intended, but I receive the error regardless. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) use it the same way:
 `# Update all the headlines with pub_date in 2007.
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2007).update(headline='Everything is the same')`. But I'm not sure why it's acting as if I'm still trying to do a field lookup on the queryset

serializers.py

```
class ShoppingListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ShoppingList
        fields = ('vin', 'img_url', 'year', 'make', 'model', 'grade',
                  'colour', 'MMR', 'run_date', 'timestamp', 'lane', "trim",
                  "mileage", 'human_valuation', 'run_no', 'adesa_id', 'engine',
                  'transmission', 'wheel_drive', 'interior_color', 'seller_announcements',
                  'auction_location', 'extra', 'check')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # look up the supplied vin, rundate and check fields before POSTing
        # if the instance exists then just update

        vin = validated_data["vin"]
        run_date = validated_data["run_date"]
        check = validated_data["check"]

        lookup = ShoppingList.objects.filter(vin=vin, run_date=run_date, check=check)

        # if lookup exists then update that instance instead
        if lookup:
            print("Updating old record")
            lookup.update(**validated_data)
            print(lookup)
            return lookup

        return ShoppingList.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

models.py

```
class ShoppingList(models.Model):
    vin = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    img_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Check Online")
    make = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Check Online")
    model = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Check Online")
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Check Online")
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Check Online")
    MMR = models.TextField(default="n/a")
    check = models.TextField(default="n/a")
    run_date = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Check Online")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)  # updated timestamp
    lane = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="Check Online")
    trim = models.CharField(max_length=60, default="Check Online")
    mileage = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Check Online")
    human_valuation = models.TextField(default="0")
    run_no = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Check Online")
    adesa_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="n/a")
    engine = models.TextField(default="n/a")
    transmission = models.TextField(default="n/a")
    wheel_drive = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="n/a")
    interior_color = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="n/a")
    seller_announcements = models.TextField(default="n/a")
    auction_location = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="n/a")
    extra = models.TextField(default="n/a")
```

Comment: Can you please post the *full* traceback?

Comment: My _suspicion_ is that your problem is with the `return lookup` line - that's still a `QuerySet` rather than a model instance, whereas if your filter gets no matches you're returning a single `ShoppingList` model instance. So if consumers of that return value expect a model instance, you might get this kind of exception - and the fix is to `return lookup[0]` instead, since you've already ensured that it's non-empty. But the full exception would help confirm or deny this theory.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper That worked perfectly, thank you. I knew it was a simple fix, if you want to post an answer I'd gladly accept it. Also should I be calling `lookup[0].save()` as well? According to the docs `update()` does not save it

Comment: You only need to `save` if there's custom saving behavior (eg from an overridden method or a signal processor) - the `update` call edits the db directly. I'll put it on an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the `return lookup` line - that's still a `QuerySet` rather than a model instance, whereas if your filter gets no matches you're returning a single `ShoppingList` model instance. So if consumers of that return value expect a model instance, you'll get this kind of exception. One fix is to return `lookup[0]` instead, since you've already ensured that it's non-empty.

You might also be able to use the [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) convenience method - put `vin=vin, run_date=run_date, check=check` in the query kwargs and `validated_data` in the `defaults` arg.

Comment: Sorry was a bit late! thanks again, I'll try that method too!